# avg in query - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this query

```
  SELECT salary
    FROM worker W
    JOIN single_user U ON u.users_id_user = W.single_user_users_id_user
    JOIN university_has_single_user US ON US.single_user_users_id_user = U.users_id_user
    JOIN course C ON C.id_course = US.course_id_course
    JOIN formation_area FA ON FA.id_formation_area = C.formation_area_id_formation_area
   WHERE FA.area = "Multimédia"
GROUP BY users_id_user
```

...that gave this output:

```
salary
--------
1400.00
800.00
```

How can I calculate the avg of this output? If I add:

```
SELECT round(avg (salary), 0)
```

...the output is again 1400.00 and 800.00, not the avg (because the group by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 SELECT AVG(DISTINCT salary)
   FROM worker W
   JOIN single_user U ON u.users_id_user = W.single_user_users_id_user
   JOIN university_has_single_user US ON US.single_user_users_id_user = U.users_id_user
   JOIN course C ON C.id_course = US.course_id_course
   JOIN formation_area FA ON FA.id_formation_area = C.formation_area_id_formation_area
  WHERE FA.area = "Multimédia"
```

Because the `salary` column is not wrapped in an aggregate, [per the documentation, the values you see are arbitrary (can't be guaranteed 100% of the time)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Usually, you'd need a derived table to get the average of the distinct values but [MySQL's AVG supports using `DISTINCT` within it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg).

Comment: the problem that i have is for example a person that have two courses have the salary repeated two times. Fine now

Comment: but for different different person also can be same salary..

my question is that - is it needed to put distinct over there???